# TypeError while programming a discord bot

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py, currency

```
Ignoring exception in on_message
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 343, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "main.py", line 162, in on_message
    checo_fifa()
  File "main.py", line 99, in checo_fifa
    Debts['checo'] = Debts['checo']+1
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

line 162 is:

```
if msg.startswith('$checo fifa'):
  checo_fifa()
  await message.channel.send('+1')
```

line 99 is:

```
def checo_fifa():
   Debts['checo'] = Debts['checo']+1
```

Debts is a dictionary containing the key 'Checo' as well as a value of 0. There are some more usernames in the dictionary as well as functions pointing to all of them. Weirdly enough, the program worked for a while but now it only returns this when writing the command in discord.

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The error is pretty clear, Debts is not a dictionary, it is a string. try checking if you have used it as a string somewhere. more code would help.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot add +1 to a string or a list, only to an integer. So you would have to convert this to a integer (if possible) e.g. with

```
def checo_fifa():
   Debts['checo'] = int(Debts['checo']) + 1
```